# Firefox is adding height to anchor

Tags: firefox, height, anchor, padding

My problem is that Firefox is adding 2px to the height of the anchors in my nav. I'm controlling the height by adding padding to the anchors that are nested inside a list.

It's throwing my nav height off and things aren't lining up.

When I inspect the elements, the heights are:
FF: 20px
IE: 18.4px
Chrome: 18px

How do I make sure the heights are the same? I'm adding padding to the anchors so that the whole button is clickable instead of just of the words. Any ideas?

```css
ul, li{
    padding: 0;
}
li{
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 0;
    background-color: bisque;
    display: block;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I see the same problem using a row of buttons and inline-block anchors styled to look like buttons. In this case, the anchor heights are all 2 pixels shorter than the buttons in Firefox. In other browsers both are the same height, as would be expected. Only solution I could find was to set an explicit height on the buttons and anchors, which seems to work across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's giving a different height, but to fix it I specified the height of the li and it seems to work. Wish I knew why it has a different height in the first place though.